# How to combine two matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices-

```
A=[1;0.5;0.67;0.72;0.88;0.9]; %// which is 6 X 1, matrix

B=[0.951  0.736  0.437  0.176   0.036;   %// which is 5 X 5, matrix
     0    0.077  0.069  0.037   0.009;
     0    0      0.439  0.531   0.365; 
     0    0          0  0.154   0.210;
     0    0          0      0   0.310]
```

I want to combine these two matrices and make [6 x 6] matrix which is like below-

```
C= [1  0.951  0.736  0.437  0.176   0.036;   %//which is 6 X 6, matrix
    0   0.5   0.077  0.069  0.037   0.009;
    0     0   0.67   0.439  0.531   0.365; 
    0     0     0    0.72   0.154   0.210;
    0     0     0       0   0.88    0.310;
    0     0     0       0      0    0.9  ]
```

To do so, I have initialized `B` as `B(6,6)=0` but I cannot combine these two.

Matlab experts, need your valuable suggestion and help.

Comment: Does it matter what happens to values that are already in place of the new values? Or will `B` always be upper triangular?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way I can think of:

```
C = zeros(6,6);
C(1:end-1,2:end) = B;
C(eye(6)>0) = A
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

```
B(end+1,end+1) = 0;
C = diag(A) + circshift(B,[0 1]);
```

returning:

```
C =

    1.0000    0.9510    0.7360    0.4370    0.1760    0.0360
         0    0.5000    0.0770    0.0690    0.0370    0.0090
         0         0    0.6700    0.4390    0.5310    0.3650
         0         0         0    0.7200    0.1540    0.2100
         0         0         0         0    0.8800    0.3100
         0         0         0         0         0    0.9000
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
C = [zeros(size(B,1),1) B; zeros(1,size(B,2)+1)] + diag(A);
```

This works by extending `B` in one row and one column, and then adding the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use the [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html):

```
full(spdiags([A, [zeros(1, 5); spdiags(B)]], 0:5, 6, 6))
```

which can be generalized to:

```
full(spdiags([A,[zeros(1,size(B,2));spdiags(B)]],0:size(B,1),numel(A),numel(A)))
```